# How to use a string variable in a directory path

Tags: vb.net

How can I join two strings in a directory path?

E.g.

```
Image.Image = Image.FromFile("MY STRING\image.png")
```

The `MYSTRING` variable contains a string.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Path.Combine()` when dealing with string paths, You can do this as follows:

```
 Image.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(MYSTRING, "image.png"))
```

Comment: One reason that `Path.Combine` is superior to the alternatives is that it will produce the correct path whether or not the first `String` ends with a delimiter and also whether or not the second `String` starts with a delimiter.  It will handle cases whether neither, on or both contain delimiters, where simple concatenation may not without extra validation code.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to concatenate Strings:
As you have a white space in `MY STRING`, I'm guessing it's a literal String.
Try one of these:

If `MY STRING` is a literal String:

**Plus Operator**

```
Image.Image = Image.FromFile("MY STRING" + "\image.png")
```

**String.Concat**

```
Image.Image = Image.FromFile(String.Concat("MY STRING", "\image.png"))
```

If `MYSTRING` is a variable:

**Plus Operator**

```
Image.Image = Image.FromFile(MYSTRING + "\image.png")
```

**String.Concat**

```
Image.Image = Image.FromFile(String.Concat(MYSTRING, "\image.png"))
```

Please see:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat-vbnet

Comment: Concatenating multiple literals in any way is just silly and the concatenation operator (`&`) should ALWAYS be used in preference to the addition operator (`+`) when concatenation is the aim. They work the same way in some cases but not all.